# Image renders in browser address bar, but not in HTML image tag

Tags: html, image, browser

I have an HTML test page with only the following image tag:

```
<img src="http://media.kohls.com.edgesuite.net/is/image/kohls/2021314?wid=130&amp;hei=130&amp;op_sharpen">
```

When I open this **test.html** in any web browser, the image will not render. Instead, it shows the broken image link icon.

[image]

But if I paste only the URL of the image directly into the browser address bar, it displays the image without issue.  Does anyone know how I can display this image in an `<img>` tag? This problem only seems to occur with images from Kohl's department store.  This is an open graph image for one of their products (og:image).

I have tried replacing the `&amp;` codes with just `&`, but this did not solve anything.

Comment: Please make a jsFiddle example.

Comment: Good idea: https://jsfiddle.net/t2LbfLuf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the server is expecting a literal `&amp;` instead of the usual `&` to delimit fields. In HTML, they need to be escaped:

```
<img src="http://media.kohls.com.edgesuite.net/is/image/kohls/2021314?wid=130&amp;amp;hei=130&amp;amp;op_sharpen">
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's... horrible!